# product id and staff id will not change when search button is clicked

Tags: php, sql

i have this code that works as a form. so whenever i have selected product id and staff id and when i click search, the product description, price will appear(the info is taken from the database). and once i am done typing in the rest of the information for quantity, pos and receipt number, i will click submit. all these information will then go into my database sql.

but i am facing a problem whereby whenever i have searched for the product id and staff id in the database, it will refresh. so the product id and staff id will go back to what it originally is, which means the wrong ids will be inserted. how do i make the page not refresh/change the ids whenever search is being clicked but still get the product description and price from the database? or how do i not make the variables (staff id and product id) be lost upon refresh?

```
<div id="login-form">
<form method="post">

<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('ishop');

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM tbl_product";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='100'>";


    echo "Product ID: <select name='product_id' class='form-control input-lg'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['product_id'] ."'>" . $row['product_id'] ."</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('ishop');

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM tbl_user";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='100'>";


    echo "Staff ID: <select name='UserName' class='form-control input-lg'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['UserName'] ."'>" . $row['UserName'] ."</option>";
    }


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input name='lookup' type='submit' id='lookup' value='Search'>";

    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['lookup']))
{

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];


        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');


        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_des FROM tbl_product where product_id ='$product_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='100'>";

        echo "Product Description: <select name='product_des' class='form-control input-lg'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['product_des'] ."'>" . $row['product_des'] ."</option>";
        }


        echo "</form>";

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}


if(isset($_POST['lookup']))
{

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');


        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT price FROM tbl_product where product_id ='$product_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='100'>";

        echo "Price: <select name='price' class='form-control input-lg'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['price'] ."'>" . $row['price'] ."</option>";
        }


        echo "</form>";

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}


if(isset($_POST['lookup']))
{

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');

        echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='100'>";

        echo "Quantity: <input type ='text' name='qty' class='form-control input-lg'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}



if(isset($_POST['lookup']))
{

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');

        echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='100'>";

        echo "POS: <input type ='text' name='POS' class='form-control input-lg'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}


if(isset($_POST['lookup']))
{

        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');

        echo "<table align='center' width='40%' border='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='100'>";

        echo "Receipt Number: <input type ='text' name='ReceiptNumber' class='form-control input-lg'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}
?>



<tr>
<td><button type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use ajax if yo dont want to refresh the page.

Comment: Or save the ID's in a session / cookie

Comment: @Epodax how do i save the id's in a session/cookie?

Comment: y so many `isset()` for same condition??

Comment: no dee to store in session / cookie. any hoy you would have written query like,`select * from table where product id = "post value of product id" and staff id = "post value of staff id", save the values in some variables instead of session

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The variables are lost upon refresh... No matter how many different variables you store the value in.

Comment: or when you r fetching, fetch those values also

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The values comes from user input.

Comment: you are using in select query means, you can select product id, staff id,* in select

Comment: how do i not make the variables be lost upon refresh?

Comment: tel me one thing, after running query, what you r doing? showing data in some place??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to either use a session or a cookie.

Using a [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) would look something like this:

```
$_SESSION['product_id'] = $product_id;
```

For the session you need to remember to start it by placing `session_start();` at the top of your page. Another thing to be aware of this that you'd need to make a logic that if you "willingly" change the product id / staff id also updated the `$_SESSION` values. (This also concerns when using cookies).

And for a [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) something like this:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

Comment: where shld i place $_SESSION['product_id'] = $product_id; in my code?

Comment: @epodax no need to store in session. coz u have the value to run query, after that you r displaying result from the query result, so just select required id in query and use it in the way you r using other details.

Comment: @Celine.Tan You place it where you fetch / set the $product_id.